# $\mathcal{Z}_1 \vDash \phi(x) \iff \mathcal{Z}_1 \vDash \phi(-x) $

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

We consider the language $L_{Ab}=\{0,+,-\}$ and the structure $\mathcal{Z}_1 = \{\mathbb{Z},0,+,- \}$. How do we show that for all $L_{Ab}$-formula  $\phi(x)$, we have $\mathcal{Z}_1 \vDash \phi(x) \iff \mathcal{Z}_1 \vDash \phi(-x) $

Comment: Because... $x\to-x$ is an automorphism of $\mathcal{Z}_1$?

Comment: What does $\mathcal{Z}_1 \vDash \phi(x)$ mean when there is a free variable $x$ in there?  Perhaps is means (by definition) $\mathcal{Z}_1 \vDash(\forall z)\phi(x)$